# Expectation of X divided by Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Say we have two continuous independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. I understand that

$E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$

but what about $E[X/Y]$. Can I say:

$E[Xg(Y)]$ where $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$

$E[X]E[g(Y)]$ by linearity

Then solve for each? If not then how does one go about solving this type of problem?

Comment: There is no linearity here, but indeed $X,Y$ independent implies $E[f(X)g(Y)]=E[f(X)]E[g(Y)]$ for given functions $f,g$, assuming the expectations make sense.

Comment: you will have that $E[X/Y]=\int x/y f_{X,Y}(x,y) d(x,y)$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

Comment: You can say that, $E[X/Y]=E[X]E[1/Y]$, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us analyze this through the lens of the product distribution. First let there be a random variable $Z = {1 \over Y}$. Since $Y$ is independent of $X$, $Z$ is also independent of $X$.

For two independent random variables, the expectation of their product is the product of their expectations. This can be proved through the Law of Total Expectation.

$$\mathbb E(XZ) = \mathbb E_Z\mathbb E_{XZ | Z}(XZ | Z))$$
$$\text{and given } Z \text{ is a constant in } XZ \text{ of inner expression...}$$
$$=\mathbb E_Z(Z \cdot \mathbb E_{X | Z}(X))$$
$$\text{and due to independence...}$$
$$=\mathbb E_X(X) \cdot \mathbb E_Z(Z)$$

To come back to your original problem...

$$\mathbb E\left({X \over Y}\right)$$
$$= \mathbb E\left(X \cdot {1 \over Y}\right)$$

$$=\mathbb E(X \cdot Z)$$
$$=\mathbb E(X) \cdot \mathbb E(Z)$$
$$=\mathbb E(X) \cdot \mathbb E\left({1 \over Y}\right)$$

However, it is very rarely the case that $\mathbb E\left({1 \over Y}\right) = {1 \over \mathbb E(Y)}$

Jensen's inequality states that if $U$ is a random variable and $\varphi$ is a convex function, then $\varphi(\mathbb {E}(U)) \leq \mathbb E(\varphi(U))$.

If $U$ is strictly positive, then $1 \over U$ is convex. Then ${1 \over \mathbb {E}(U)} = \mathbb E\left({1 \over U}\right)$ only if $U$ has zero variance.